# How to replay the tutorial in Crusader Kings 3?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I got Crusader Kings 3 and started the tutorial on a prompt. But I quit before finishing it.

Now I can't seem to find the option to play it again. Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replay the tutorial by clicking on "Play Tutorial" in the upper right hand corner of the "New Game" screen (the screen where you select start date & character).

[image]

Comment: I guess with my resolution I must have missed those tiny letters!

Comment: It is very small and tucked away in the corner, they probably should make it glow or something.